# Importing Code Formatter Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I want to ident my Java's code with the Google's style. 
So I download the last version of checkstyle from the orginal source:

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html

I extract It so I get a checkstyle_packages.xml on my directory.
I run Eclipse:

In Eclipse I go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

I click Import

I select checkstyle_packages.xml

But It doesn't import anything.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: At the top there is a drop down "Active Profile". Did you select your imported XML?

Comment: Why *should* that work? Nowhere is it said that that's an exported Eclipse Java Formatter profile. You can't just pick any XML file.

Comment: @Kon No, because my imported XML's file doesn't appear in any Active Profile. I don't understand why not.

Comment: @nitind I did what this tutorial teachs: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ImportFormattingRules What should I do instead ?

Comment: @Igna94 dlamblin's answer.

Comment: You did what that tutorial says, except you picked an entirely different XML config file from a different tool. That almost never works.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can only use that Import to import files which as designed to work with the Eclipse formatter. Importing files which are for any other formatter will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to get the xml from here:

> https://github.com/google/styleguide

You can also find JetBrains IDEA (IntelliJ) xml files in this repository which are the only ones I personally have experience with.

As far as I'm aware these don't require the use of checkstyle.